# Scroll bar in SAP UI5

Tags: sapui5

How can i control scroll bar position for a sap.m.page. That is on click of a button, the page should be scrolled to top.
I tried using "page.scrollTo(10,0)", but didn't work.
Please correct me if m wrong.

Thanks,
Sathish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one which i tried is correct, but the positive values is for scrolling down.
So i have done like this

"page.scrollTo(-10,0)"

Its working for me.

Regards,
Sathish